# How to run Atmosphere Sample?

Tags: java, comet, atmosphere

I have just downloaded the Atmosphere Samples from Github. When I ran jetty:run goal on the chat-sample, I have some problems.

I can access to the page (http://localhost:9090) with my browser, but when i start chatting, nothing append, because the server return an 404 error page for each AJAX request.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you tell me which atmosphere release are you using ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and was able to solve it by running jetty not through maven but with jett-runner. You have to download 2 jars:

```
wget http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-websocket/8.1.4.v20120524/jetty-websocket-8.1.4.v20120524.jar
wget http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-runner/8.1.4.v20120524/jetty-runner-8.1.4.v20120524.jar
```

build the war with:

```
mvn package
```

and than you can run it by:

```
java -jar jetty-runner-8.1.4.v20120524.jar --jar jetty-websocket-8.1.4.v20120524.jar  --path /atmosphere target/atmosphere-chat.war
```

now you can open your browser to:

```
http://localhost:8080/atmosphere/
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok something similar happened to me recently. Along with no message being sent, there were also 404 errors for all the JS files. Thats when I realized that trailing slash in `http://localhost:9090/` is important :)